# django-rest-framework override get_queryset and pass additional data to serializer along queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

This is a toy example of the problem that I am facing. For some reason, I am unable to pass the expected data to my serializer and that is raising the following error.

AttributeError at /my-end-point/

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `main_data` on serializer `ParentSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'main_data'.

```
class MainModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MainModel


class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
    main_data = MainModelSerializer(many=True)
    extra_data = serializers.FloatField()
    

class View(ListCreateAPIView):
    
    serializer = ParentSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # extra_data would have some calculated value which would be a float
        extra_data = some_calculated_value()
        queryset = MainModel.objects.filter(some filters)
        
        return {
            'main_data': queryset,
            'extra_data': extra_data
        }
        
        
# expected data that is passed to the ParentSerializer

# {
#     'main_data': queryset,
#     'extra_data': extra_data
# }
```

Comment: get_queryset only return a queryset. Can't return a dict

Comment: So is there a way to send additional data to my serializer?

Comment: You can override list method https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Comment: I did that but pagination class wasn't working with that.

Answer (score 1):

Look's like you have two problems:

1. Incorrect return value for `get_queryset` method
2. Passing some extra data to serializer

As for the first one you simply should not override that method or return a queryset. Depending on how extra data is being computing there can be the tradeoffs like [annotating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) value on queryset and specifying it in serializer [fields list](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer).

For the second one - if annotation is not an option and you'd like to calculate value one's, the possible solution is to add extra data to serializer [context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) and use it as return value of [serializer method field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). In this case extra data will be placed on the same level with model records data (extra field for each model record):

```json
{
    'model_field_1': 'value',
    ...
    'extra_field': 'value',
}
```

Or you can continue using your approach with [nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) by override `list` (and `create`, if needed) - just add extra data to serializer validated data, so that the result will look like this:

```json
{
    'extra_data': 'value',
    'main_data': [
        {'id': 1, 'field1': 'value', ...}
        ...
    ]
}
```

```py
class View(ListCreateAPIView):
    
    serializer = ParentSerializer
    
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # extra_data would have some calculated value which would be a float
        extra_data = some_calculated_value()
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        data = self.get_serializer(qs, many=True).data
        data['extra_data'] = extra_data
        return Response({'data': data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, content_type = 'application/json' )
```

Comment: the problem with the nested solution is that the serializer's method field is called for each row of the table which hits the database 'n' times for 'n' rows. I want 'n' rows from the database and just one value for the 'extra_data'

The response would look something like this:

{
'main_data': [{...}, {...}, {...},... ],
'extra_data: (a float value)
}

But with nested approach I get this:

[ {...main_data, 'extra_data' : float}, {...main_data, 'extra_data' : float}, ...]

Comment: Second approach from my answer will do exactly what you need, nested appoarch refes to many records will be serialized into list of dicts, not to your extra data added to each of list dicts. Also, if value passed through context it won't be hitting DB more then one's when it's being calculated in view. Finally, if for some reasons (probably not because of the problem your facing now) you'll want to avoid extra hits to get same value in serializer - you can decorate serializer method field with [LRU cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to achieve is to pass some extra data to the `ParentSerializer` to be returned by the `list action` on your view.But you have multiple problems in your code:

1. `get_queryset` is only used to return an instance of `models.QuerySet`, which is used to determine which model objects the view is allowed to perform any kind of actions on.
2. This is a follow up on the first point, `get_queryset` is not used to pass data to the serializer, this is done during the `Serializer` initialization.
3. You are using `ModelSerializer` but you're not specifying the `fields` attribute on the `Meta` class which is not allowed anymore since `drf version 3.3`, you have to define either a `fields` attribute or an `exclude` attribute.

As for actually how to pass that extra data to the Serializer, you can do that in multiple ways:

1. define a SerializerMethodField as proposed by [Charnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996863/charnel) in his answer which is described by the drf docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), your serializer will look like this:

```
    class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        main_data = MainDataSerializer(many=True)
        extra_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name="some_calculated_value")

        def some_calculated_value(self, obj):
            # calculate value here
            return value
```

Note that this field is a read only field.

2. You can inject the calculated value to the end result during validation, this will make your serializer look like this:

```
    class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        main_data = MainDataSerializer(many=True)

        def validate(self, attrs):
            attrs["extra_data"] = some_calculated_value()
            return attrs
```

3. You can also do it by overriding `list` function on the View and change the data passed to the serializer.

I personally prefer option number 1 since `SerializerMethodField` fits the purpose, while the `validate` function should be used only for validation to abide by the single responsibility concept.